# nurbs curve not bending mesh correctly

Tags: modeling

on this car tire model, the nurbs curve is not bending the mesh (surface of intended car tire) correctly:
It is obvious what I mean by looking at this screenshot, and feel free to inspect my blend file:  https://app.box.com/s/s7vi3l06lf9vv6ir9j5ysfz9t0v9qhka
[image]
what i want is the mesh perfectly (smoothly) aligning, bending exactly right together at each end. I've been trying for hours to manipulare the nurbs curve, and since i'm a newbie to blender, still don't know how to fix the curve just right.
Any tips?
Cheers / Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to reset the object rotation values for the nurbs curve so that it is exactly 90 degrees on the X and Z axis. Then it will line up correctly.

[image]